# Listing of Directories

Tags: windows

A user wants to make sense of a very messy Windows shared drive, and asked for a way to print out all the directories together with their subdirectories.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

I have never tried this but in theory can you not use command prompt (cmd) then change to the directory you require....run the following

```
tree > tree.txt
```

this would make you a file named tree.txt listing the tree of the directory it was run from

or another would be (replace Folder with the folder in question)

```
dir /d /s C:\Folder > C:\mydir.txt
```

This would make a file name mydir.txt in the root of C:\

hope that helps.

Comment: wow, good ol' tree still works!  love that about microsoft

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Treesize Free](https://www.jam-software.com/freeware/index.shtml).  It'll show you the directory structure, and how much space each folder is using of the total disk size.  Very handy tool for shared drive cleanups.

[image: Treesize Free Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [jam-software.com](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/screenshots/EN/freeware_treesize_kl.gif))</sub>

Comment: That is nice little utility...thanks for posting link

Comment: Treesize has saved me many times!

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to the exact question but also useful for making sense of drives is https://windirstat.info/

[image: windirstat example]

Comment: Windirstat is a great utility.

Comment: Another nice utility, once again thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

Use the command:

```
dir /S /B /A:D
```